# How to run the python script for many files?

Tags: python, biopython

I have a script which sort FASTA sequences, alphabetically based on strings after >. Here is example of code which works with a single input file 35.fas.

```
import os, sys
import argparse
from Bio import SeqIO

records = list(SeqIO.parse("35.fas", "fasta"))
records.sort(key=lambda x : x.id)
SeqIO.write(records, "35-sorted.fas", "fasta")
```

Example of fasta file:

```
>BAR
ATCG
>ABC
TCGA
```

Correct output:

```
>ABC
TCGA
>BAR
ATCG
```

So, I want to try this for hundreds of files and tried 'sys.argv' but was not able to do so. I do not want to have different output name as *-sorted for each file. Just want to run the script and sort all files in a folder with the extension of .fas.
Here is the code didn't work:

```
records = list(SeqIO.parse("sys.argv[0]", "fasta"))
records.sort(key=lambda x : x.id)
SeqIO.write(records, "sys.arg[0]-sorted.fas", "fasta")
```

Comment: `sys.argv` is probably going to be needed. Can you show how you tried to use it? What OS are you using? The problem could be a limitation on the length of the command line if you have hundreds of files. You may need to specify the directory and have the python code get the files from it.

Comment: I added the code to the question, and I'm using macOS. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have been incorrectly using `sys.argv`, it is an array of all command line parameters, with the first being the file being ran itself, for example look at the following:

```
import sys
for f in sys.argv:
    print(f)
```

When you drag the files a.txt, b.txt and c.txt onto the script it will print the following (with ... being the omission of the full path):

> .../a.txt
>
> .../b.txt
>
> .../c.txt

You can implement this into your script as:

```
import os, sys
import argparse
from Bio import SeqIO

for f in sys.argv[1:]:
    records = list(SeqIO.parse(f, "fasta"))
    records.sort(key=lambda x : x.id)
    SeqIO.write(records, f[:-4] + "-sorted.fas", "fasta")
```

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly easy to iterate over all the filenames in `sys.argv` (you should omit the first entry, which is the program name) with a `for` loop. You are then left with the problem of generating the output filenames. I'm assuming for the sake of argument that all filenames end in `'.fas'`. If that's not the case it the string manipulations would a little tricker, but not too awful.

```
import os, sys
import argparse
from Bio import SeqIO

for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
    records = list(SeqIO.parse(filename, "fasta"))
    records.sort(key=lambda x : x.id)
    outname = filename[:-4]+'-sorted.fas'
    SeqIO.write(records, outname, "fasta")
```

Assuming this program were called `myprog.py` (and that you aren't on Windows, which may require you to expand the wildcard name using the `glob.glob` function) you would then call it like

```
python myprog.py *.fas
```

Comment: Thanks. It give syntax error!     records = list(SeqIO.parse(filename", "fasta"))
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Remove the unwanted quote at the end of filename